# Question answered 8 months before it was asked

Tags: bug

This answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138999/100397 appears to have been answered in June 2014. But the question was only asked in February this year (2015).

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look under the revisions history of the question you'll notice that the older answer was merged into this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/185829/revisions.

[image]